# Digital Pen too sensitivite

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, digital-pen

I'm using the [GPEN300](http://www.iogear.com/product/GPEN300/) from [IOGear](http://www.iogear.com/).

I use this pen as a tablet input on my desktop.

The problem is that instead of getting a full 8.5x11 until I hit the corners of the screen, I only get an area of about 5x8.

I tried changing the mouse sensitivity settings to make it slower but that only affects the mouse and not the pen input.

Is there any setting that can make the digital pen move less extremely on my computer?

I realize this may be difficult as the typical tablet input actually touches the screen but maybe there's some calibration feature that I can play around with

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product page lists an installation CD, have you tried the software that came with it, or were there just drivers?

You can check control panel and device manager for additional configurations.

User Review extract form Amazon:

> ...The second one I emailed them first to see if there was a way to
>   calibrate the pen and they replied within a day. There isn't a way to
>   calibrate the pen, but they suggested pulling the ink refill out and
>   putting it back in. I did that, and found a ball of lint inside the
>   pen and cleaned it out, but it didn't help.

[http://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-Mobile-Scribe-Digital-GPEN300/dp/B004GB8URY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004GB8URY)

Hope this helps.